# Plesk panel Cronjob delete folder older then x days

Tags: cron, plesk

i'm trying to set a cronjob on plesk panel to remove folders in a directory /uploads/temp_files.
I'm using this command: 
`find /uploads/temp_files/* -type d -ctime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;`
but i get an error from plesk: -: find: command not found

what can i do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full path. Instead of **find** use **/bin/find**. Depending of your linux distro, the location might be differnt. On a ssh shell console use this:

```
which find
```

The output will show you the exact location of **find**. Then use that full path in your cron job!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't have access to ssh only to plesk panel. Can i command to plesk panel to remove folders in this directory? See screenshot: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2136456/0350b9c98fad92da238270bf3a8a7863

Comment: You could ask them or, create the cron job from your plesk interface but use full path for find like /bin/find instead of just find

Answer (score 0):

Because of security reasons hosting providers use chrooted shell.
In case your subscription has chrooted shell you have limited access to server commands and there is no `find` binary in Plesk default chrooted shell.

You can check it by following path "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/bin/" in "File Manager":

[image: Plesk chroot bash]

In this case you may ask your hosting provider to add `find` in your subscription or in common chroot template by following KB: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213909545--HOWTO-How-to-add-new-programs-to-a-chrooted-shell-environment-template